# Divergence Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis

I know that exist a succession of dense open sets $V_n\subseteq C(\mathbb T)$ so that $|S_Nf(0)|\rightarrow +\infty$ for $N\rightarrow+\infty$ $\forall f \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{+\infty} V_n$. ($S_Nf(x)=\sum_{|n|\le N}\hat f(n) e^{inx}$)

but $\forall x_0 \in [-\pi,\pi]$ exist a generic set $G_{x_0},G_{x_0}\subseteq C(\mathbb T),|S_Nf(x_0)|\rightarrow +\infty$ for $N\rightarrow+\infty$?

Comment: $G_{x_0} = \{f(x-x_0): f\in \cap V_n\}.$

Comment: because in general series of the functions$ f(x)$ and $f(x+c)$ simultaneously converge or diverge?

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment: Fix $x_0.$ Let $g(x)=f(x-x_0).$ Then $S_N(f,0) = S_N(g,x_0).$ I'll leave the proof of this to you for now. Try it, it's a fundamental property of Fourier series. Thus $|S_n(f,0)|\to \infty$ iff $|S_n(g,x_0)|\to \infty.$

Also note that the map $f(x)\to f(x-x_0)$ is a linear isometry of $C(\mathbb T)$ onto $C(\mathbb T).$ That is why the set $\{f(x-x_0): f \in \cap V_n\}$ is also a set of the second category in $C(\mathbb T).$